PHP how to recreate the random order of an array after chunk
For an online game I create an initial PHP array with 36 values: A-Z 0-9. A random script remix the array, i.e
[0] R
[1] 4
[2] N
[3] d
...
[35] 8

Once done the script assigns 6 signs to each of the 6 players via a chunk($arr,6).
Player 1 [0] = [R,4,n,d,O,M]
Player 2 [1] = [p,2,s,Z,k,u]
...
Player 6 [5] = [J,r,V,5,z,8]

The question is: once the table of players has been reordered alphabetically, is there an algorithmic way to recreate the initial distribution?
To simplify the question:
Initial array
[0] = abc
[1] = def
[2] = ghi
[3] = jkl
[4] = mno
[5] = pqr

Random order permutation [0,1,2,3,4,5] -> [2,5,0,3,1,4]:
[2] = ghi
[5] = pqr
[0] = abc
[3] = jkl
[1] = def
[4] = mno

Result:
new order     [0]   [1]   [2]   [3]   [4]   [5] 
value         ghi   pqr   abc   jkl   def   mno
former order  [2]   [5]   [0]   [3]   [1]   [4] -> random permutation

To retrieve former order I must find the way to produce the array [2,4,0,3,5,1]:
 new order   [2]   [4]   [0]   [3]   [5]   [1]          
 value       abc   def   ghi   jkl   mno   pqr  -> initial array order

How to obtain this array [2,4,0,3,5,1] from random permutation [2,5,0,3,1,4] ?

I don't get what you mean by "once the table of players has been reordered alphabetically" here. Where have the players been "ordered" in any other way to begin with?

Why is this question so Unclear / difficult to understand?  Why is there a mix of upper and lower case letters? Is the input actually 26 lower, 26 upper, and 10 numbers?  Why do the chunks have 6 characters, then later magically only 3 letters?  If the solution is to shuffle before chunking, then surely we have a dupe page that demonstrates how to shuffle an array.

the sole function of the 3-letter example was to simplify the problem to be solved. Forget the first part, which explained how and why.

how to shuffle a php array but keep the index in foreach and PHP Random Shuffle Array Maintaining Key => Value and shuffle() doesn't work as expected with an associative array and PHP shuffle numerically indexed object array preserve key-value

Yes, there is a way to do that. Let's assume that you have an array called $array and you shuffle it inside a function to which (very important!) you pass your array by value rather than by address. Example:
?php

$array = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];

function shuffleMyArray($array) {
    shuffle($array);
    return $array;
}

$shuffled = shuffleMyArray($array);

echo json_encode([
    'original' => $array,
    'shuffled' => $shuffled
]);

Output example:
{"original":["a","b","c","d","e","f"],"shuffled":["a","d","c","f","b","e"]}


Wouldn't $shuffled = $array; and then shuffle the new array achieve the same thing?

@NigelRen the reason why I create this as a function is that it's reusable then. If you want the same pattern, then it makes more sense to delegate the shuffling into a function instead of duplicating it many times, because if you would need to do some further stuff for the shuffled array, then you can implement the change exactly once inside the function instead of doing it as many times as many usages there are. But you are technically correct, the example you have given would do the job too, but if I see something like that in a PR, then I would request for changes.

Premature optimization doesn't have the best of rep's - still.

@NigelRen this is not a matter of optimization but it is a matter of organization. We separate the concern of shuffling from the usages of said shuffling. This will not improve performance, nor memory usage. It will actually use more memory by adding a function call to the stack, but it's worth it, because it will make the function reusable with almost no additional cost. Whereas, if you do not organize your code well, then you will later on spend hours refactoring your duplicated code and trying to figure out where you missed doing it.

Optimization is not just about performance (IMHO). But bloating a 2 line piece of code for something that may never happen in this limited scenario adds extra complexity which is simply not needed.

@NigelRen it is a good idea to separate concerns into units while you are implementing your code. This will 1. Greatly reduce your future code duplication 2. Allow you to implement unit tests for the separated units if you wish to do so 3. Make the code more readable, because teammates would have a harder time understanding why did we assign an array to the other one, but it's easy to understand the calling of a function called shuffleMyArray. So while your point about the alternative being technically correct is accurate, but having the concern separated is better organization in my view.

@NigelRen separation of concerns makes the code simpler, actually. It's easier to read 2000 lines of easy-to-understand short functions than to read 2000 lines of multi-purposed code. And this allows you to write unit tests too, even if the code would never become duplicated. But the point is: if you are writing your code naively, that is, you avoid "premature optimization" by not separating chunks of your code into meaningful functions, then sometimes you will end up reimplementing the same thing, no longer remembering of it being implemented somewhere else.

@NigelRen in my view SoC (Separation of Concerns) (see https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/abenseperation_concerns_guidl.htm) is a very valid principle and it allows you to write code in an organized manner and therefore, others, including your future self will have an easy time finding out what your code is exactly doing. It allows you to organize your code into units, makes it easier to apply dependency injection where it is supposed to be, makes it easy to reuse your code, which is of value in its potential even if it does not end up being reused.

@NigelRen let's say that you solve 100 small problems and you consistently do not apply SoC for them and there is a 23% chance that some of those solutions would be needed again. Having them "lost" in thousands of lines you will not necessarily know at all that the small problem has been solved and even if you know it, the code not being fresh, it will be difficult and more stressful to refactor at that point. The other approach is to apply SoC 100 times, that is, you separate your code into functions.

I think you are comparing 2 different scenarios, if I had to write a 10 line piece of code to do something, I would write it very different to a full scale site.  The principles are different and have different purposes.  If you move to classes, you would again write in different way with appropriate practices.

@NigelRen in comparison, in the first scenario you are very slightly quicker to write the code, but 23% of the 100 cases will cause you troubles later on, each of them causing you more problems than applying SoC consistently. So, at the expense of taking a few extra steps to organize your code, you achieve 1. Higher stability 2. Ease of understanding (and better success in maintaining the code) 3. Reusability 4. Portability 5. Ease of maintenance and adjustments 6. Testability

23% of what is 3 statements equates to 0 lines of repeated code. Your theory is right but applying it at any scale just doesn't add up IMHO.

@NigelRen I would not measure these chunks by the number of lines, but by the number of problems they are supposed to solve, a.k.a., the number of units. I would advocate the use of classes too, but that would be a too far-fetched thing to do at the space of this answer, because we want to help OOP programmers and procedural programmers alike.

@NigelRen I would be very proud to have this theory, but the author is Edsger W. Dijkstra in an 1980 article in Springer-Verlag. In the example I have given, the 23% (a number arbitrarily chosen just for the sake of an example, it's not a statistic, but a thought experiment only) would be the ratio of codes which would be needed to be repeated, once, twice, or even more times. And then imagine that you have the shuffling implemented at 10 different places and then it turns out that you need to log it... Or something like that.

@NigelRen a further benefit I have mentioned but you did not react to yet is that it allows for the implementation of unit tests. Take for example the case when a small code chunk is in its own function and you have some unit tests for it. Then, it starts to misbehave due to some other changes you made in the code. The unit tests would instantly tell you that there is an error in this function specifically and therefore fixing the problem would be much easier. I'm not advocating for fanaticism of applying this principle each and every time you write code,

@NigelRen but even though we are not perfect in applying this principle, having all its benefits is clearly superior than not having its benefits. And the cost for it is a small time of organization while implementing the code which is far outweighed by the time you would spend refactoring and bug fixing if the principle would not be applied and problems would arise from it. In terms of memory use, you add a single function call to the stack per unit, which is a code that we should be willing to pay IMHO.

An interesting analogy - you have spent over a page explaining the benefits of adding a 2 statement function.

@NigelRen others spent articles and books on it, but I'm also happy to share my thoughts and knowledge. It's up to you to decide whether all this makes sense to you, but the bottom line is that both approaches are correct, but there are reasons why we want to separate concerns.


Store your former order using array_flip
Shuffle the array (you may use lajos-arpad suggestion to preserve the original array)
Obtain the new order using array_map by mapping shuffled value to its original position

    $array = ['abc','def','ghi','jkl','mno','pqr'];
    $former_order = array_flip($array);
    // ['abc' => 0, 'def' => 1, 'ghi' => 2, 'jkl' => 3, 'mno' => 4, 'pqr' => 5]
    shuffle($array);
    // ['abc','mno','def','ghi','pqr','jkl']
    $new_order = array_map(fn($item) => $former_order[$item], $array);
    // [0,4,1,2,5,3]

